# ¿Como podria generar un query que muestre un número en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Por favor tengo una duda en como podria generar un `query` que muestre:

- Un número entero (sin parte decimal) aleatorio entre 0 y 100.
- Un literal numérico fijo.
- La raíz cuadrada de ese número.
- y el resultado de elevar ese mismo número a la 3.

Estoy utilizando una base de datos de `Northwind` en `MySQL`

Esta es la sintaxis que estoy armando:

```
SELECT ROUND(((20 - 1) * RAND() + 1), 4)
```

El resultado esperado debería ser:

```
aleatorio: 3 Literal: 7 raíz 2.6457513110645907 Potencia 3
```

Comment: Este la sintaxis que estoy armando SELECT ROUND(((20 - 1) * RAND() + 1), 4)

Comment: el resultado esperado deberia ser: aleatorio: 3 Literal: 7 raiz 2.6457513110645907 Potencia 3

Comment: No entiendo, las operaciones que deseas hacer provienen de valores de dicha base de datos o ¿por qué la incluyes?

Comment: Si provienen de valores de esta base datos, es un ejercicio abierto no especifica  una tabla en particular, lo ves posible realizar??? el maestro que me da clase me indica que el resultado debe quedar con las siguientes tablas: aleatorio: 3 Literal: 7 raiz 2.6457513110645907 Potencia 3

Comment: De ser posible pero como ya te habían indicado, si agregas lo que has intentado seguro recibes ayuda

Comment: ¿El `literal número fijo` sería un número que se elige a mano y listo? ¿Las columnas serían `aleatorio, literal, raiz y potencia`?

Comment: Si, asi seria la estructura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que lo que buscas es algo como este código

```
SELECT ROUND(((100 - 1) * RAND() + 1), 0), 20, SQRT(20), POW(20,3)
```

**Referencias**

- [Elevar al cubo](https://riptutorial.com/es/mysql/example/15816/elevar-un-numero-a-una-potencia--pow-)
- [Raiz cuadrada](http://mysql.conclase.net/curso/?sqlfun=SQRT)

Comment: Gracias sin embargo el maestro que me da clase me indica que el resultado debe quedar con las siguientes tablas: aleatorio: 3 Literal: 7 raiz 2.6457513110645907 Potencia 3  y la sintaxis enviada me da aleatorio: 39 Literal: 20 raiz 4.47213495499958 Potencia 8000

Comment: Dos cambios: 1. El aleatorio es entre `0` y `100`, no entre `1` y `100`. 2. Cambiar el `20`, por `7`. Sugerencia: agregar los alias.

Comment: Super!!! Mil Gracias quedo muy agradecido listo. Saludos